# Combine one-arg functions into a multi-arg one in Clojure

Tags: clojure, function-composition

I wonder if there is an idiom in Clojure for combining several one argument functions into a new function accepting a vector. The new function should apply the first function to the first argument and so on.

I think this is useful in a number of situations. For example, you might want to transform x, y and z coordinates of a point using simpler unidimensional functions.

I would implement by myself as follows but I'm afraid it should already exists something similar in the standard API.

```
(defn vector-comp [& fns]
  (fn [avect]
    (vec (map #(%1 %2) fns avect))))
```

Comment: Note `(vec ...)` instead of `(into [] ...)`.

Comment: In fact the casting to vector is usually not necessary in Clojure - sequences work in most of the cases where vector does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/useful/fn.clj#L90

Comment: Congrats on the [clojure] badge. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Other way to write this:

```
(defn vector-comp [& fns]
    #(map apply fns % (repeat nil)))
```

I am 99% sure there is no ready-made solution in the standard libraries (`juxt`comes the closest that I know of)